Book about a boy who was blown up or involved in a fire and had to be replaced by robotics, then helped the government or some agency solve crimes
When I was in school, an author came in and showed us their new book; this would have been anywhere from around 2010-2014, I think.
It was about a boy who (I think) was blown up or involved in a fire and had to be replaced by robotics, then helped the government or some agency solve crimes. I believe it was based in the UK and the cover had a guy with long dark hair.
Sorry I can’t remember more, but it’s been bothering me for so long that I can’t remember the book.

"I believe it was based in the UK": does it mean that when you met the author you were in the UK? And that the author is from the UK?

Is this Bionic Agent (2010) by Malcolm Rose...? It was followed by one sequel, Cyber Terror (2011).
From a review:

A massive explosion destroys the south of England, but one boy is saved and his damaged body is rebuilt. He becomes a member of the mysterious agency, Unit Red and given a new name. No longer plain Alan Smith, now he is Jordan Stryker and he has superhuman powers which he must use for the good of the country, tracking down the perpetrators of one of the biggest crimes ever known.



It was released within the specified time period.
The cover shows a young man with long dark hair and a bionic arm.
The story is set in the UK and the protagonist is a boy named Alan Smith who's injured in an explosion, then rebuilt with bionic parts, recruited by a crime-fighting agency called Unit Red, and given the new name of Jordan Stryker.

